# How to use passed parameter in view in MVC Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Due to issues with db I am not able to use MVC Controller Details so I am passing data to my own view and creating my own details view.

This is my link with parameter:

localhost/something/2

How can I access that 2 in my view and for example reuse it in

```
foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.ID == MYPASSEDPARAMETER))
```

Comment: So you just dump the entire table into the view, and let the view find the requested item in all the records? That sounds _really_ bad. Sure, you can get an answer to this question (_"Just put it in the ViewBag"_), but you really better work towards fixing your "issues with db" .

Comment: that's what I would plan to do after creating something which works and can be shown to others... How would I put it in viewBag/use ViewBag to filter data?

Answer (score 0):

*How can I access that 2 in my view*

one way is: using `QueryString`

```
@Request.QueryString["id"]
```